# How to group list of list inside value

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class DetailsLocal {
    private String accountNumber;
    private List<OptionType> optionTypes;
}

public class OptionType {
    private String typeCode;
    private List<String> optStrtgTpCode = new ArrayList<>();
}

List<DetailsLocal> accountDetailsLocalList = new ArrayList<>();

42317415        EQUOPT      PUTWRITING  
42317415        EQUOPT      PURCHHEDGE  
42317415        EQUOPT      COMBUNCOV   
42317415        INDEXOPT    COMBCOV     
42317415        INDEXOPT    COVCALLWR   
42317415        INDEXOPT    PURCHOPT
```

Want to group 2nd column with another list of last 3rd column. Could someone shed some light on this?

I want this in DetailsLocal with optionTypes list

```
List<DetailsLocal> =42317415    ,optionTypes :  typeCode=EQUOPT ,List<String> optStrtgTpCode = PUTWRITING ,PURCHHEDGE ,COMBUNCOV ;
     List<DetailsLocal> =42317415   ,optionTypes :  typeCode=INDEXOPT,List<String> optStrtgTpCode = COMBCOV,COVCALLWR,PURCHOPT;
```

Comment: the question is not clear with respect to what input you already have and what output you are looking for, maybe if you could share your attempt, things would be slightly better.

Comment: Input I listed in 6 rows of data, my requirement is here to single row by grouping EQUOPT and have it in DetailsLocal

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you might be expecting something like below,

```
Map<String, List<OptionType>> collect = detailsLocals.stream()
                                                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DetailsLocal::getAccountNumber,
                                                         Collectors.mapping(DetailsLocal::getOptionTypes,Collectors.toList())
                                                 ));
```

This produces the below result,

```
{42317415=[OptionType{typeCode='EQUOPT', optStrtgTpCode=[PUTWRITING, PURCHHEDGE, COMBUNCOV, COMBCOV, COVCALLWR, PURCHOPT]}]}
```

OR

```
Map<String, List<OptionType>> collect = detailsLocals.stream()
                                                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getOptionTypes().getTypeCode(),
                                                                     Collectors.mapping(DetailsLocal::getOptionTypes, Collectors.toList())
                                                             ));
```

it gives you,

```
{EQUOPT=[OptionType{typeCode='EQUOPT', optStrtgTpCode=[PUTWRITING, PURCHHEDGE, COMBUNCOV, COMBCOV, COVCALLWR, PURCHOPT]}]}
```

Just my assumption and try. You could choose which one you want or clarify more details to know better understanding as Naman mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output data structure looks to be a nested grouped mapping. Currently assuming the input data is of type `PresentDetails` such as:

```
record PresentDetails(String accountNumber, String typeCode, String optStrtgTpCode) {}
```

You need to construct a temporary variable that could comprise the required data with the help of `grouping`. You might also need to map the final `List<String>` to get the codes list.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> intermediate = presentDetails.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PresentDetails::accountNumber,
                Collectors.groupingBy(PresentDetails::typeCode,
                        Collectors.mapping(PresentDetails::optStrtgTpCode,
                                Collectors.toList()))));
```

Now if you look at each entry type of this `Map` it would look very similar to the `DetailsLocal` and you can achieve the result of further mapping these entries for your purpose.

```
List<DetailsLocal> accountDetailsLocalList = intermediate.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(outerEntry -> new DetailsLocal(outerEntry.getKey(),
                outerEntry.getValue().entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(innerEntry -> new OptionType(innerEntry.getKey(),
                                innerEntry.getValue()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```